# HTML5 JQuery RSS Reader

Tags: jquery, html, rss

I found an RSS reader and I made some changes to it. It gave me "Application Error".  "(file:///android_assset/www/index.html)".

I thought the reason was that it's trying to download huge data so it crashed.
What I did is this:

I downloaded all the Javascript and CSS from the server and tried to access it locally. But it's showing a blank screen.

This one gives the above mentioned error:

```
<html class="ui-mobile"><head><base href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/">   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">   <title>- jsFiddle demo</title>    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css">
      <style type="text/css">
```

And this one gives the Blank Screen:

```
<html class="ui-mobile"><head><base href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/">   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">   <title>- jsFiddle demo</title>    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.mobile-1.0b2.min.css">
      <style type="text/css">
```

Comment: Which RSS reader did you download? Link? What changes did you make? Does it work without your changes?

Comment: @Chris Sorry I don't remember from where I have downloaded it. And it doesn't matter what I actually changed in the script. Please check the question again as I have updated it now.

Comment: I cannot see anything related to an RSS reader in the code snippet you posted. All this seems to do is load jQuery (mobile) and start defining some CSS.

Comment: @Chris There is a problem in Loading jQuery and CSS itself.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a document type for your HTML document. Your browser might assume that it is HTML 4 which does not allow a `class` attribute on the `html` element.

Try adding the [HTML5 doctype](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#the-doctype) to the start of the document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: It was working all fine. The only problem was that the app was trying to download too much things at a time on a low bandwidth phone. So decided to download all .js and .css in the app directory before hand itself so that there won't be so much burden on phone bandwidth. I hope you understood what I mean to say.

Comment: I understand. But from the code you posted, this is the only error I could find.